# Detecting Mechanical Button Press with Python3 and QT5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, raspberry-pi3, gpio

I have an application that is developed in Python 5.3 and PyQt 7.1 (I think).  So far I have everything in the GUI working just fine.  I now need to be able to detect the pressing of two external mechanical buttons via GPIO.add_event_detect.  I added the GPIO command for detecting the falling edge of the signal and when I try to execute the code I get the "Conflicting edge detection already enabled for this GPIO Channel."
I tried moving the the code to different classes (it's not in a while loop) just to see if I would get a different error.
I am looking for any documentation or instructions that explains how to use the add_event_detect into an event based application like QT.
As always, much thanks!
Mike

EDIT:
I tried the recommendation below and I am having an issue with execution.  The code below is only three classes - I didn't add a executable code because I wasn't sure anybody would want to spend time to add 2 N.C. buttons to GPIO pins.  I am hoping you'll be able to see an issue just by reading the code.

The class ExecuteSession works fine.  I am trying to add the ability to read the falling edge of two signals on the GPIO pins 16 & 18 in classes PStop and EStop.  When the ExecuteSession starts I can see the print statements "In PStop" and "In EStop".  When I push the buttons I don't see the other print statement.  I am pretty new to Python and Threads and would appreciate any suggestions.

I did create a small test program to make sure the Pi was seeing the state transition, and it did.

Thanks

```
class PStop(QThread):

    PT_event_detected = pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.queue=Queue()
        GPIO.add_event_detect(16, GPIO.FALLING, callback=self.queue.put)
        print("In PStop")

        def run(self):
            while True:
                print("In PStop Run")
                self.PT_event_detected.emit(self.queue.get())
                print("PT EVENT " +str(self.queue.get()))

class EStop(QThread):

    ER_event_detected = pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.queue=Queue()
        GPIO.add_event_detect(18, GPIO.FALLING, callback=self.queue.put)
        print("In EStop")

        def run(self):
            while True:
                print("In EStop Run")
                self.ER_event_detected.emit(self.queue.get())                
                print("ER EVENT " +str(self.queue.get()))

class ExecuteSession(QThread):

    PBValueSig = pyqtSignal(int)
    PBValueDone = pyqtSignal(int)
    PBValuePause = pyqtSignal(int)
    PBTimeActual = pyqtSignal(int)

    durComplete = 0

    def __init__(self, dur='', pause='', stopExe =''):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.dur = dur
        self.pause = pause
        self.stopExe = stopExe

        self.E_Stop = EStop()
        self.E_Stop.ER_event_detected.connect(self.Ext_Stop_Detect)
        self.E_Stop.start()

        self.P_Stop = PStop()
        self.P_Stop.PT_event_detected.connect(self.Ext_Stop_Detect)
        self.P_Stop.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.stop()

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        i = 1
        while i <= dur: #self.dur:
            iA = i
            if self.stopExe == True:
                durComplete = i
                i = self.dur + 1 #Complete

            elif self.pause == False: #12/15 added el
                self.PBValueSig.emit(i)
                i = i + 1
                durComplete = i
                time.sleep(1)
        self.PBTimeActual.emit(iA)
        time.sleep(1)
        self.PBValueDone.emit(durComplete)

def Ext_Stop_Detect(self, channel):
    print("CHANNEL " +str(channel))
```

Comment: PyQt 7.1 ??????Python 5.3 ????? what?? You are in a very distant future

Comment: show your code.

Comment: uhhh...I am old!  Python 3.5 and QT 5.?

Comment: Your question is unclear, edit your question and add the code you have tried, in addition to explaining what is your problem.

Comment: It would also help if you tagged this with the [tag:raspberry-pi] tag

Answer (score 2):

The error you are seeing is likely due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38125047/1994235) issue. While you may not actually have it in a while loop like that question, chances are you **are** calling it multiple times because you've got it in a Qt callback or similar. Anyway...on to how to integrate it with Qt...

The `GPIO.add_event_detect` method takes a callback to be executed on a state change of the GPIO port. The code monitoring the GPIO runs in a separate thread, which means the callback is run in a separate thread. This poses some problems for integrating with Qt, as you need to make sure you do it in a thread safe way (if you do it wrong, you'll probably end up with an error like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37394390/1994235)).

A simple solution is to assume that Qt signals are thread safe when called from Python threads (which is what the GPIO library will be using). This is a bit of an open question as far as I'm aware, as technically they are documented as not being thread safe when used from Python threads, but typically I've found it to be OK. If you want to take the risk of your program crashing occasionally, then this is how you do it "simply"

I'll assume you have a subclass of `QMainWindow` in your program, but this will work added to any Qt class:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    event_detected = pyqtSignal(int)
    def__init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.event_detected.connect(self.on_gpio_event)
        GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.BOTH, callback=self.event_detected.emit)

    def on_gpio_event(self, channel):
        # your code here!
        print("An event occurred on channel {}".format(channel))
```

Alternatively, doing it the "definitely safe" way involves slightly more work. Here you tell the GPIO library to place any events into a thread safe Python queue, which is thread read out by a QThread which emits the Qt signal (Qt signals are definitely thread safe when used from QThreads)

```
from six.moves.queue import Queue

class RelayThread(QThread):
    event_detected = pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QThread.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.queue = Queue()
        GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.BOTH, callback=self.queue.put)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.event_detected.emit(self.queue.get())

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def__init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.relay_thread = RelayThread()
        self.relay_thread.event_detected.connect(self.on_gpio_event)
        self.relay_thread.start()

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_gpio_event(self, channel):
        # your code here!
        print("An event occurred on channel {}".format(channel))
```

Anyway, hope that helps. It's a bit hard to do any more without specific code from you, but in general, this is how you interface the GPIO ports on a raspberry pi with the Qt event loop.

Comment: three-pineapples, that your for the instructions.  I will review and try, but if unsuccessful, I will create a sample code and post.  Thanks again.

Comment: One more question...can a thread spawn a thread?  I am already using QThread/Qt signal, and the button detection will impact an execution thread.  So can I have a thread spawn another thread (nested?) or should I keep separate?

Comment: Yes, that's fine to have threads spawning other threads. Possibly if it's a `QThread` spawning a `QThread`, then you need to set the parent correctly when you construct it (which I think just means doing `second_thread = QThread(self)` or similar).

Comment: three_pineapples, I added the code based on your suggestion and an explanation of what is happening.  Can you please take a look and see if you have any suggestions?  This is not executable because it requires two NC switches connected to the GPIO.  Just looking for a core review to look for obvious errors in code.  Thanks

Comment: @Mike I think your issue is indentation errors. a), your `run` method in the `PStop` and `EStop` classes are indented too far (they are **inside** the `__init__` methods so don't correctly override `QThread.run`). b) Your `run` methods get from the queue twice per iteration. This will get separate events. You should read from the queue only once per iteration. If you need to use the value twice, read from the queue into a variable and then emit/print that variable. c) I think you have some indentation errors in `ExecuteSession.run` but since that's not part of this question, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: continued...d) What happens in the `__init__` method of a `QThread` is actually run by the parent thread, not by your new thread. This means your current setup has the MainThread launching 5 separate threads: The ExecuteSession thread, the PStop thread, the EStop thread and the two threads for monitoring the GPIO. There is nothing wrong with this at all, but just wanted you to know since you had previously asked the question about threads spawning threads (which is not how you currently have it set up). Hope that makes sense!

Comment: It's starting to make sense.  On "b)" you say it's reading twice.  I don't have enough knowledge/experience to understand why, but is there a way to resolve?  I only need to read once - maybe I don't need a queue, because once this external signal goes low I will terminate the ExecuteSession thread.

Comment: That was it - indentation was wrong.  Thanks!!!!!  I see what you were saying about it executing twice.  Is there anything I need to change/fix that?  Thanks again.